# How to track a magnet (roughly) with a magnetometer

Tags: android, ios, sensors, spatial

I was interested in using the magnetometer of a device to track a magnet that is moving around it. I'm roughly just interested in knowing when the magnet is to the left/right/top/down of the device (essentially very coarse tracking).

Does anyone have any tips on this? I've looked around for a while and haven't been able to find much :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is physically impossible. A magnet is a dipole, meaning that the [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field) around it doesn't simply point in the direction of the magnet. The sensor only senses the direction of the field. From this it can not calculate the direction of the magnet.

Comment: Hmmm ok, this makes a bit more sense. Would it then be possible to sense the direction of the field from the magnet?